# remove a range of channel entries

Tags: channel-entries, sorting

I have the following entries. I would like to only display only a range from entry 5 and on.  how do i remove 1-4 from the entries and keep the rest?

**Entries**

- 2016-02-08 Entry 1
- 2016-03-01 Entry 2
- 2016-03-29 Entry 3
- 2016-05-02 Entry 4
- 2016-05-15 Entry 5
- 2016-05-30 Entry 6
- 2016-09-12 Entry 7
- 2016-10-24 Entry 8
- 2016-11-01 Entry 9
- 2016-12-06 Entry 10

**Code**

```
            {exp:channel:entries channel="events" orderby="event_start_date" sort="asc"}
                 {event_start_date format='%Y-%m-%d'} {title} 

            {/exp:channel:entries}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to always skip a set number of entries you can use `offset=x` as described in the docs: https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/channel/channel_entries.html#offset

Comment: first thank you for the reply.  I would be more interested in a date range like what the current date is and everything after that date to be displayed.   so for the example above it would only show entries 7-10.

Comment: <pre>{exp:channel:entries channel="events" orderby="event_start_date" sort="asc" }
 {if {current_time format="%Y-%m-%d"} >= {event_start_date format='%Y-%m-%d'}}
  {event_start_date format='%Y-%m-%d'} <a href="{event_website}">{title}</a> <br>
 {/if}
{/exp:channel:entries}</pre>  something like this but this outputs all of the entries..

Comment: If you use the default entry_date you can use `start_on='today` parameter: https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/channel/channel_entries.html#start-on